# Why can't the event be triggered when the iOS view moves

Tags: ios, uievent

I tested it. When I moved the View, the tap event on the view doesn't respond, and it only responded when it stopped. I don't know why this happens. Below is my code

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIView *testView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.testView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    self.testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:self.testView];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTestView:)];
    [self.testView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
- (void)tapTestView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    
    NSLog(@"Event triggered");
    
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:6 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.testView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 400;
        self.testView.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a pan gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to make sure to use [`animatewithduration:delay:options:animations:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622451-animatewithduration?language=objc) with the [`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/uiviewanimationoptionallowuserinteraction?language=objc) option. If you do not use this option, animated views will not receive touches.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:26 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.testView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = ...;
    self.testView.frame = frame;
} completion:nil];
```

Second, when views are animated, if you examine the `frame` of that view as it is moving, you will see that the `frame` property won’t reflect where the view really is at that moment of time, but, rather, where it will eventually be. Specifically, the `frame` property will be that value you set in that `animations` block, even if it hasn’t finished actually moving there, yet.

The implication of this behavior is that, even if you enable user interaction during animation, as shown above, gestures will be recognized based upon the view’s final destination rather than where it is now. E.g., if you start animation of frame from rect A to rect B, the gesture recognizer will recognize taps within rect B even if the view is not there yet! And conversely, it won’t recognize taps where the animated view happens to be, because the `frame` effectively thinks the view is already at the destination.

To get around that issue, one must refer to the view’s layer’s [`presentationLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentationlayer?language=occ) to get the location of the view mid-animation. One approach is to add a gesture recognizer to the main view and then, in there, see if the touch was inside the animated view’s presentation layer:

```
- (void)tapMainView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.testView.superview];
    CGRect frame = self.testView.layer.presentationLayer.frame;

    BOOL isInTestView = CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point);

    if (isInTestView) {
        [self testViewAction];
        return;
    }

    // otherwise, we're in the super view
    [self mainViewAction];
}
```

Alternatively, you can (a) define a `UIView` subclass for the child view and (b) override its `hitTest` implementation to factor in the presentation layer:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:self.superview]]) {
        return self;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want to explore is why I can’t respond to events when moving, not how to respond to events. Your answer is a bit unclear. But thank you for your answers

Comment: As I attempted (and apparently failed) to say above, the reason you aren’t responding to events while animating is twofold: First, during animation, user interaction is simply disabled unless you use that option I outlined above. Second, if you look at the `frame` property mid-animation, you’ll see that it really is at the final destination, not the current location (resulting in weird behavior where taps on final destination will be recognized, but not where the view actually is). So you have to use one of those techniques that use the `presentationLayer` rather than the view’s `frame` value.

Comment: I later checked some information. The animation we saw was actually some changes in the value of presentationLayer. The real position information was modelLayer. The location where we trigger the event is not in the View. It should be this kind of understanding。